# No muestra todos los caracteres en el PDF con FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Comparto la función que estoy usando, funciona perfectamente el único problema es que cuando mando a imprimir el PDF se imprime perfectamente sin errores pero en una sección con un msj "LARGO" no me muestra todas las letras, e intentado ya muchas soluciones sin conseguir una posible solución.

Por otra parte aun que no se me muestren los caracteres restantes el pdf si los esta recibiendo porque al momento de señalar(resaltar) toda la oración con el cursor y pegarla en otra parte se pega toda la oración como si estuviera completa pero no muestra los caracteres.

Les incluyo imágenes para que puedan ver lo que sucede y de antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

[image: Esta es la sección del PDF donde no se muestra la oración completa]

[image: este es el msj que deberia observarse, esta img pertenece a la interface de usuario]

```
function ParametrosTabla($header,$data)
{



    $this->Ln(5);

    //Colors, line width and bold font
    $this->SetFillColor(220,220,220);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('','B');



    //Column widths

    $w=array(84,100);
    $w2=array(88,100);


    //Header

    $this->Cell(2);

    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)

        $this->Cell($w2[$i],5,$header[$i],0,0,'L',true,false);

    $this->Ln(7);



    //Color and font restoration

    $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);

    $this->SetTextColor(0);

    $this->SetFont('');



    //Data

    $fill=false;
    $tipoAnt="";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)

    {

        if ($tipoAnt!=utf8_decode($data[$i]['nombre_tipo']))
        {
            if ($tipoAnt!="")
                $this->Ln();

            $this->Cell(2);
            $this->SetFont('','B');
            $this->Cell($w[0],3,utf8_decode($data[$i]['nombre_tipo']),0,1,'L',$fill);
            $this->SetFont('');
        }
        $this->Cell(6);
        $this->Cell($w[0],3,utf8_decode($data[$i]['nombre']),0,0,'L',$fill);

        if($i==0)
            $this->MultiCell($w[1],3,utf8_decode($data[$i]['observaciones']),0,'J');
        else
            $this->MultiCell($w[1],3,' ',0,'J');
        //$this->Ln();

        $tipoAnt=utf8_decode($data[$i]['nombre_tipo']);

    }



}
```

Comment: En que parte se ve exactamente el inconveniente de que no muestra los caracteres? Yo trabajé con esa librería un tiempo, y solucionaba eso con  `MultiCell`, seguro lo estás aplicando correctamente?

Comment: Fíjense en la primera imagen,en la ultima palabra, debería ser "COMPLEMENTARIOS" Sin embargo solo se observa "COMPLEMENT" es justo hay el problema y se podría pensar que no se esta trayendo bien de la base de datos pero cuando copio con el cursor esa linea la oracion esta completa solo que por alguna razon no se imprime por completo esa palabra